# No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Pow' on Android

Tags: android, kernel, tensorflow

I use custom inception model of Android and when I try session->Run() I receive following error: 
No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Pow' with these attrs. [[Node: gradients/Pow_2_grad/Pow = Pow[T=DT_FLOAT](sub_2, gradients/Pow_2_grad/sub)]]

This error appears only when I build Android application via bazel build.

As I understand from [there](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1269) I should add necessary OpKernel to Android operator sets in [BUILD](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD) file. But I don't understand what OpKernel I should add to Android operator set in case of Op 'Pow'?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In this case it's cwise_op_pow.cc:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_op_pow.cc

I usually do a grep in tensorflow/core/kernels for '"Pow"' or whatever the op name is if I'm having trouble tracking down the right file.

Comment: Thank you, I've fixed issue with kernel for 'Pow' and some else, but unfortunately I can't find proper kernel for  'LRNGrad'. I get such error: Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'LRNGrad' with these attrs.  Registered kernels:  <no registered kernels>. I've added in Android Build all available kernels by means of //tensorflow/core/kernels:android_all_ops in core/kernels/BUILD